# Why can't I see any result? Sub program

Tags: python, function, python-3.5

I'm making a program to find out how many times something appears in a file (which will be read by Python) - my first step (just to make sure wha I'm doing is correct) is to see the whole file opened in Python.. if you get me?

```
def input_function():
    my_file = open("ChoralShieldData.csv", "r")

    ChoralShieldData = []

    for each_line in my_file:
        ChoralShieldData.append(each_line.split())

    return ChoralShieldData


#Main program
ChoralShieldData = input_function()
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: So what did you expect to happen? Where do you print the value of the  `ChoralShieldData` global?

Answer (score 1):

Neither you print the result nor you write the result in your file. That's why you can't see any result.

Answer (score 0):

You haven't told the code to show you anything. At the moment all it is doing is storing the data in your variable `ChoralShieldData`.

Try adding this to the very bottom of your code (pick one only):

```
print ChoralShieldData #Python 2.x
print(ChoralShieldData) #Python 3.x
```

Alternatively, add a similar `print` statement anywhere in your function to see what it is doing at specific stages.

See [here for some more help](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) on reading from and writing to files.